# MCE error message and random reboots

Tags: boot, kernel, hardware, mint, dmesg

May someone help me in decoding the exact significance of the following message I found in `dmesg`?

```
Jan 28 15:58:17 mint kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 7: 8c00004000010093
Jan 28 15:58:17 mint kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 5159cf02b8 ADDR 529449f80 MISC 2040404086
```

There are many of them, but `CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 7: 8c00004000010093` is constant among them.

I understand the CPU is detecting hardware problems, but I don't understand **where**. Maybe a failed memory stick on bank 7? (I got 8 banks fully populated).

I found another thread where it was advised to install `mcelog`, but `apt` finds no packages named `mcelog`.

---

EDIT:

The system completed one pass of memtest and was left running it for a whole night. It remained rock solid.

Here is what `/var/log/syslog` shows:

`Sep 13 13:40:11 mint ntpd[1462]: kernel reports TIME_ERROR: 0x41: Clock Unsynchronized
Sep 13 13:44:25 mint kernel: [  648.820738] mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
Sep 13 13:44:25 mint kernel: [  648.820770] EDAC sbridge MC0: HANDLING MCE MEMORY ERROR
Sep 13 13:44:25 mint kernel: [  648.820778] EDAC sbridge MC0: CPU 0: Machine Check Event: 0 Bank 7: c01fbb4000010093
Sep 13 13:44:25 mint kernel: [  648.820778] EDAC sbridge MC0: TSC 0 
Sep 13 13:44:25 mint kernel: [  648.820779] EDAC sbridge MC0: ADDR 0 
Sep 13 13:44:25 mint kernel: [  648.820780] EDAC sbridge MC0: MISC 0 
Sep 13 13:44:25 mint kernel: [  648.820786] EDAC sbridge MC0: PROCESSOR 0:306e4 TIME 1536846265 SOCKET 0 APIC 0`

It appears it's a memory related error, but it seems to me that the system reboots during I/O operations on disks.

The machine keeps rebooting randomly. Any help would be incredibly welcome.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?  `mcelog` was found in 'universe' https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mcelog until it was removed upstream in debian.   It was reported, confirmed (1752251) with three alternatives provided for bionic, but no work done; nor anything confirmed.

Comment: I successfully compiled and installed mcelog from sources. It doesn't work though. I'll keep trying. Besides, I'd really like to know why my question was downvoted.

Comment: You may have a bad RAM stick. Run **memtest** from the GRUB menu or after booting a Ubuntu Live DVD. Report back to @heynnema.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you! How long should I run memtest? For now, a quarter hour was passed successfully.. I can even leave it on for a whole night if necessary.

Comment: 1 or more complete passes is fine. You might also check that you have the latest BIOS installed, and the intel-microcode or amd64-microcode installed also. Also make sure that your {Bay Trail} processor chip isn't one of the ones that require a kernel boot flag modification to operate properly.

Comment: 1 pass done without error. I got the latest BIOS. My cpu is not a bay trail. It's a Xeon e5-2630v2. I didn't install any microcode: indeed, we are talking about a live distribution: I never got to complete a system install without a reboot. Note that during memtest no reboot happens. Hmmm maybe I bent a CPU pin? The machine is freshly assembled.

Comment: Check /var/log/syslog for events around the time of the reboots. That should give us a clue. Make sure to place @heynnema into your comments, or I may miss them.

Comment: I've added an answer for you. Please remember to accept it if it was helpful, and ultimately helped solve/identify your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the comments...

Although memtest seems to run OK, all indications are that you have an intermittent memory problem with **Bank 7: c01fbb4000010093**.

It may be a RAM memory module failure, or a RAM memory module seating failure, or a defective memory slot on your motherboard.

If your memory slots are identified with bank numbers on the logic board, mark the memory module in bank 7 with a black magic marker pen. **Assuming that all of your memory modules are the same brand/make/model**, rotate ALL of the memory modules **ONLY ONE SLOT** over, such that RAM memory module bank 7 ends up in bank 6. Make sure that you use proper ESD grounding techniques when handling RAM modules. Rerun memtest, noting any failures.

If memtest runs OK, then reboot the system, and if it runs fine, you've solved the problem. If it fails with a bank 6 error (or anything other than bank 7), you've identified the defective memory module.

Memory modules should be installed/removed in pairs. One module is normally on memory channel A, and the other on memory channel B. This is for memory interleaving purposes. If you wish to fully identify/eliminate a specific RAM module, remove it, and its interleaving mate, reboot the system, and retest.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do it as soon as I can do it calmly and without hurry. I know which bank is 7 by the mb manual. But Still, not managing to stay up for 10 minutes with IO operations while completing hours and hours of memtest makes me think I bent some IO pin on the cpu socket. Furthermore, note that my memory is buffered and ECC, so it's capable of correcting errors, up to some extent. It's worth trying, though.

Comment: Unused memory gets used as disk and I/O buffers, so failures during disk I/O may not be surprising... esp if you have a fast SSD. If you had a bent pin on the CPU, the CPU wouldn't fit nicely into its socket, and you'd have much bigger problems that what you have.

Comment: Ok, I did as advised. Rotated memory modules. MCE error on bank 7 persists, as well as random reboots. Then I removed the memory modules on banks 7 and 8 (former 7). MCE errors on bank 7 persists. The memory modules seem to be blameless. Are we sure that that "bank 7" actually refers to memory bank 7? Anyway, note that the pins are on the mobo, it is the cpu that actually got "sockets" see https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2JAGNWve4X0/maxresdefault.jpg ; However yes, I got a fast ssd (nvme). I think I'll ditch the mainboard and buy another one.

Comment: Depending on how they numbered the banks/sockets, bank 7 may not directly correlate to the one marked bank7... it might be bank 6 or bank 8. Next step, remove all but the lowest 4 RAM modules and retest. If it works, add 2 more RAM modules and see if it works. Just assure that you're adding them correctly to keep them paired for memory interleaving.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it, but it's a quad channel system. If I remove one, it'll go in single channel, if I'll remove two, it'll go in triple channel, etc. Thanks!

Comment: That's OK. By removing two at a time, you're correct, it'll go to a lower channel count... but we're just testing... so with your 4 channel system, you may have to remove 4 at a time to keep the max channels working. If that's the case, the remove/swap process is only slightly different. Remove 4. Retest. Replace existing 4 with the removed 4. Retest. If that all works, then we try the existing 4 in the other 4 slots. Retest. Replace the existing 4 with the removed 4. Retest. Get the idea?

Comment: Ok, I ended up with just 1 memory module in bank 1 (the system does not power up without memory in that bank, no matter what you do with the others). Nothing. MCE on bank 7 persists. I downloaded the efi version of Intel Processor DIagnostic Tool (it stresses the memory too). It was passed successfully. Some 2 minutes after that, the system rebooted. I got to say that it's an hard reset: that is, the system shuts itself down (no current from psu), then it goes on automatically within a couple of seconds.

Comment: Brought a ssd with windows: it boots but goes BSOD within minutes, with exit codes Machine Check Exception or "WHEA" (I don't know what this means. Edit: see this: https://neosmart.net/wiki/0x0000124-whea-uncorrectable-error/). @heynnema

Comment: I am tired of this sh*t. I ordered a new mainboard, mate. Your efforts on my behalf, no matter how unfruitful, have to be considered commendable. Thanks :)

Comment: Fair enough. Please keep me posted.

Comment: Sure, I expect to rebuild the system within the next week.

Comment: @MadHatter status please. Inquiring minds want to know how you're doing.

Comment: Hi @heynnema! The board arrived yesterday, I think I'll rebuild the contraption during the WE. Rest assured, I'll inform you in due time. Thanks! :-)

Comment: I built the new system with a fujitsu D3128-B2. I'm using it with half the memroy from another machine, and it works perfectly. I also order specific memory for that board in order to avoid surprises. As a final note, I carefully examined the cpu pins on the old board. No pin was bent. I think the board was defective in some other component. Thank you for your support, mate! @heynnema